# Passing arguments with ExecJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, execjs

I need to execute a javascript function from within my Rails 4 application. I tried the following with ExecJS (https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) without any success:

```
my_js_function = 'function my_function(a){var b=a.split("$");var c="";for(i=0;i<=b.length-1;i++){if(!(i%2)){c+=b[i]}}var b=c.split("");c="";for(i=0;i<=b.length-1;i++){if(i%2){c+=b[i]}}return c}'
compiled_function = ExecJS.compile(my_js_function)
result = compiled_function.call(my_argument)
```

The original JS function takes an argument (my_argument), which I somehow need to pass on to it. Any help on how this is possible will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. You should not use `call`, you should use `eval` this way:

```
my_js_function = 'function my_function(a){var b=a.split("$");var c="";for(i=0;i<=b.length-1;i++){if(!(i%2)){c+=b[i]}}var b=c.split("");c="";for(i=0;i<=b.length-1;i++){if(i%2){c+=b[i]}}return c}'
compiled_function = ExecJS.compile(my_js_function)
compiled_function.eval('my_function("heyhey")')
#=> ehy
```